# post variable in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to post the variable `var projectid=data.projectid,` the same as i did with:

```
                    url: "rapportage/rapport_detail?idKlant=" + klant,
```

the ajax call look like this:

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "rapportage/rapport_detail?idKlant=" + klant, 
                        dataType: 'json',
                        error: function(){ alert("Onvoldoende gegevens beschikbaar om rapportage to genereren."); },
                        success: function(data){ // Plaats data op de juiste plek in de tabel 
                        var projectid=data.projectid,
                            titel=data.titel,
                            projecttype =data.projecttype,
                            projectleider =data.projectleider,
                            projecttype =data.projecttype,
                            statusproject =data.statusproject,
                            startproject =data.startproject,
                            deadlineproject =data.deadlineproject,
                            omzetproject =data.omzetproject,
                            kostenproject =data.kostenproject,
                            margeproject =data.margeproject,
                            totaalurenproject =data.totaalurenproject,
                            totaalminutenproject =data.totaalminutenproject,
                            urenkostenproject =data.urenkostenproject;
        var str='';
        for(var i=0,len=titel.length;i<len;i++){
           str+="<tr>"+"<td>" + titel[i] + "</td>";
           str+="<td>" + projectleider[i] + "</td>";
           str+="<td>" + projecttype[i] + "</td>";
           str+="<td>" + statusproject[i] + "</td>";
           str+="<td>" + startproject[i] + "</td>";
           str+="<td>" + deadlineproject[i] + "</td>";
           str+="<td>" + "&#8364;" + omzetproject + "</td>";
           str+="<td>" + "&#8364;" + kostenproject + "</td>";
           str+="<td>" + "&#8364;" + margeproject + "</td>";
           str+="<td>" + totaalurenproject + ":" + totaalminutenproject + "</td>";
           str+="<td>" + "&#8364;" + urenkostenproject + "</td>"+"</tr>";
           }
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        $("#details tbody").append(str);
                                                }
                                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this;

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "rapportage/rapport_detail?idKlant=" + klant, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var projectid=data.projectid;
        ........
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "rapportage/rapport_detail?idKlant=" + klant, 
            data: "projectid=" + projectid,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {

            }
    }
    .....
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to work because the data:projectid has no value there because its done before the var projectid = data.projectid

Comment: I assumed you have already that variable, so you you want too resend it after first ajax success?

Comment: yes srry:) thats exactly what i wanted to do. i thought about something like this        var projectid=data.projectid;
$.post("rapportage/rapport_detail?idProject=" + projectid);
console.log(projectid);

Comment: See my updated answer, but you do not need to resend that request again. You can do that in first ajax request at the backend already

Comment: When i do it like that i get an NULL response but when i log it it has values in it.

Comment: Where do you get NULL? in second ajax? By the way, you need to handle `projectid` on backend responsd specific response

Answer (score 0):

i didn't get what you are asking, but if you want to post a variable by POST then you can

```
type: "POST",
url: "rapportage/rapport_detail", 
data : {"idKlant" : klan},
```

add this in ajax

Comment: @doniyor key can be string, you can try